# Unable to deploy Activiti 6

Tags: java, activiti, apache-tomee

i am very beginner to activiti and apache tomee. i have downloaded activiti-6.0.0.Beta4.zip and want to run it's activiti-app on
apache-tomee-plus-1.6.0 server with java version "1.7.0_80".
one more thing- i am able to deploy activiti 5 with same environment.but having problem in activiti 6 only. 
console logs are as below:

```
SEVERE: ContainerBase.removeChild: destroy: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/activiti-app]] in state [STARTING_PREP]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:409)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1477)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1458)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeployWebApps(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:719)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication(Assembler.java:1608)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:893)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:612)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1205)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1051)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1660)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Sep 29, 2016 12:40:10 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder startInternal
SEVERE: Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/activiti-app]
org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: /home/yogeshmishra/YogeshData/apache-tomee-plus-1.6.0/webapps/activiti-app: javax.validation.spi.ConfigurationState.getParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:897)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:612)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1205)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1051)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1660)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.spi.ConfigurationState.getParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.<init>(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:45)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.ConfigurationImpl.doPrivBuildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:252)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.util.SecureActions$5.run(SecureActions.java:131)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.util.SecureActions$5.run(SecureActions.java:129)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.ConfigurationImpl.run(ConfigurationImpl.java:337)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:244)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ValidatorBuilder.buildFactory(ValidatorBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ValidatorBuilder.buildFactory(ValidatorBuilder.java:46)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:712)
    ... 18 more

Sep 29, 2016 12:40:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/activiti-app]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1660)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: /home/yogeshmishra/YogeshData/apache-tomee-plus-1.6.0/webapps/activiti-app: javax.validation.spi.ConfigurationState.getParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1214)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1051)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: /home/yogeshmishra/YogeshData/apache-tomee-plus-1.6.0/webapps/activiti-app: javax.validation.spi.ConfigurationState.getParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:897)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:612)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1205)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.spi.ConfigurationState.getParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.<init>(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:45)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.ConfigurationImpl.doPrivBuildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:252)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.util.SecureActions$5.run(SecureActions.java:131)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.util.SecureActions$5.run(SecureActions.java:129)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.ConfigurationImpl.run(ConfigurationImpl.java:337)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:244)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ValidatorBuilder.buildFactory(ValidatorBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ValidatorBuilder.buildFactory(ValidatorBuilder.java:46)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:712)
    ... 18 more

Sep 29, 2016 12:40:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive /home/yogeshmishra/YogeshData/apache-tomee-plus-1.6.0/webapps/activiti-app.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/activiti-app]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1660)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Sep 29, 2016 12:40:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
```

Comment: This is probably a problem that has to do with library versions. The `NoSuchMethodError` most likely means that you have code compiled with one version of some library, and you're trying to run it with another (older?) version of that library. Make sure you have the appropriate versions of libraries that your code and Activiti needs.

Answer (score 0):

you have a bean validation implementation of the specification 1.1 but tomee 1 only supports bean validation 1.0 by default. Migrating to tomee 7 is surely the easiest to solve it without playing with classloading configuration.

Comment: i tried to run on 'apache-tomee-plus-1.7.1' but getting same exception on deployment time.

Comment: tomee 1.x is EE 6 so bean validation 1.0. TomEE 7 (7.0.1) is EE 7 and bean validation 1.1. Sorry if ambiguous in my last answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try other environment, i can show mine:

- Windows 10 64bit
- apache-tomcat-8.5.20
- activiti-6.0.0

Then i just put the wars into webapp, and start the tomcat, use the H2 database by default.

**Webapp locations after start**

[image: Webapp locations after start]